# redirecting output using sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, user-management

I want to run a command as another user using sudo, and redirecting the output of that command as that user.
Example, if I run:

```
touch some-file
```

under user simon, some-file will be owned by user simon. If I run:

```
sudo -u ernesto touch some-file
```

then some-file is owned by user ernesto, as I am specifying that I want to run the touch command as ernesto. Finally, if I run:

```
sudo -u ernesto ls /some-folder/ > some-file
```

some-file is again owned by user simon, as the > operator is redirecting the output of the whole command before >, to some-file (which is in fact being ran by user simon). I need to grab the output of listing a directory as ernesto but using sudo, as the directory that I want to list, is owned by ernesto, and I can't list the directory using with simon.

It has to be using sudo, as the user ernesto allows me to run sudo commands without password.

I tried

```
sudo -u ernesto $(ls /some-folder/ > some-file)
sudo -u ernesto `ls /some-folder/ > some-file`
sudo -u ernesto 'ls /some-folder/ > some-file'
sudo -u ernesto eval(ls /some-folder/ > some-file)
sudo -u ernesto exec(ls /some-folder/ > some-file)
```

hoping for something of this to work, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tee` through `sudo` to write to a file as another user.

In your use case of writing a directory listing, it becomes a simple

```sh
sudo -u ernesto ls some-directory | sudo -u ernesto tee some-file
```

Comment: Or you start a new shell with option "-s" and pass multiple commands as string with "-c". example: `sudo -u foo -s bash -c 'echo "USER=$USER and SUDO_USER=$SUDO_USER" > /tmp/textfoo'`